# Hard drive slow down suddenly

Tags: hard-drive, performance, speed

My hard drive has become very very slow and I don't know why.
You can see the performance here:

```
sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads: read(2097152) returned 28672 bytes
```

How can I diagnostic my Hard Drive and fix it?

I don't lose any data. The Hard Drive is just became super slow and I don't know why ;(

EDIT:

You can also see the output of this command:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

Here:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-36-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     HGST Travelstar 7K1000
Device Model:     HGST HTS721010A9E630
Serial Number:    JG40006PGKHV1C
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 6acc7f5c5
Firmware Version: JB0OA3B0
User Capacity:    1 000 204 886 016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jan  1 14:32:50 2017 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 117) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 174) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   178   178   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1788
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   082   082   000    Old_age   Always       -       8005
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1765
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       26038
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   181   181   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 12/50)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 65535 inconsistent with error log pointer 2

ATA Error Count: 65535 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 65535 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8005 hours (333 days + 13 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 38 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000038 = 56

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 30 38 00 00 40 00      00:03:34.637  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 28 30 00 00 40 00      00:03:34.637  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 20 28 00 00 40 00      00:03:34.636  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 18 20 00 00 40 00      00:03:34.636  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 10 18 00 00 40 00      00:03:34.636  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65534 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8005 hours (333 days + 13 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 c8 38 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000038 = 56

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 90 00 00 00 40 00      00:03:34.490  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 88 48 38 c0 40 00      00:03:31.488  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 80 20 4e c1 40 00      00:03:31.488  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 78 c0 61 c0 40 00      00:03:31.488  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 70 20 3c c0 40 00      00:03:31.488  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65533 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8005 hours (333 days + 13 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 38 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000038 = 56

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 80 38 00 00 40 00      00:03:24.703  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 78 30 00 00 40 00      00:03:24.703  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 70 28 00 00 40 00      00:03:24.703  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 68 20 00 00 40 00      00:03:24.703  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 60 18 00 00 40 00      00:03:24.703  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65532 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8005 hours (333 days + 13 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 c8 38 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000038 = 56

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 e0 00 00 00 40 00      00:03:24.547  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 d8 70 52 c0 40 00      00:03:21.545  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 d0 10 38 c0 40 00      00:03:21.545  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 c8 38 a2 84 40 00      00:03:21.545  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 c0 f0 48 81 40 00      00:03:21.545  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65531 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8004 hours (333 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 38 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000038 = 56

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 58 38 00 00 40 00      01:46:52.737  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 50 30 00 00 40 00      01:46:52.737  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 48 a0 23 b4 40 00      01:46:52.721  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 28 00 00 40 00      01:46:52.720  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      01:46:52.720  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       50%      8005         56

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

PS: it is **not** an SSD and is size is 1 To and I have 35.9 GiB free space in my Linux Partition

Comment: Have you run SMART diagnostics?

Comment: give us result of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`. If you haven't it on your system, then install it, package on all unix based systems called `smartmontools`

Comment: What kind of harddrive is it? A mechanical drive? An SSD? In case of an SSD, how much free space do you have left and how big is the drive?

Comment: I'd advise you to back up all your data from the HDD somewhere off-site. Making duplicates of your files and storing them in different storage locations is the best way to avoid any potential data loss. According to the SMART data, I wouldn't say there's anything concerning about the HDD health-wise. However, the slow performance/transfer rate could also be coming from a failed connection to it. If you haven't checked that out already, I'd strongly recommend you swap the SATA cable and the SATA port where the drive is connected to the mobo. Hopefully, it will improve the HDD's performance. :)

Comment: @SuperSoph_WD, the hard drive can still work with a failed connection? How is it possible? O_O

Comment: @Fractale, it is possible that there's a miscommunication with the SATA data cable or the SATA port itself. The HDD is still working but the system is failing to communicate with it properly, if there's something wrong with the connectivity. This usually results in slow transfer rate and it bottlenecks the HDD's overall performance. If you have access to another PC, try plugging the drive there as a secondary HDD and check how the other system will react to it. Hope it works. Keep us posted.

Comment: I found this question trying to figure out why my external drive suddenly seemed slow.  Granted, the stuff I usually do is automated like backups so I don't usually watch the speed so it could have been low for some time.  But when I went to analyze it for defragmentation, Windows says it is **21%** fragmented which seems ridiculously high!  I was under the impression that NTFS didn't ever need defragmenting.